# XMLHttpRequest cannot load error on accessing MEAN.js API through IONIC app

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest, ionic-framework, meanjs

I am developing an [ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) application, trying to access API of [MEAN.JS](http://meanjs.org/) application which is as below which is a link to encoded JSON

```
https://damp-dawn-2579.herokuapp.com/api/foods
```

The factory service of my application accesses the above link but gets an error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/api/foods. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Factory Service

```
.factory('Foods', ['$resource',
  function($resource) {
    return $resource('https://damp-dawn-2579.herokuapp.com/api/foods/:foodId', { foodId: '@_id'
    }, {
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      }
    });
  }
])
```

How do i overcome this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Enable cross request in node

```
app.all('/', function(req, res, next) 
{
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
      next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution for this error would be just adding the extension **Allow-Control-Allow-Origin:** on google chrome.

[plugin link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related)